# Web Development -- Learning Web development languages, Platform - Grails or Ruby or any other ones?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, grails

I want to spend the summer getting into web development. I have some basic C++ and Java background. I was told by some people to master HTML & CSS first then Javascript. Then someone else told me that I should go with Grails while another person told me Ruby on Rails. I've always been interested in web development but never had the time to fully learn it and now I have some free time and I'm hoping to hone my skills. 
The problem is there are so many platforms and languages that it's quite confusing. I want to eventually create a website and then embark on a tech startup. I'm quite confused. Please help. I know I need to master HTML, CSS but what do you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very subjective question and thus, not suited for SO. Developers have their own preferences.

Comment: Web development is HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Rails, Grails, Django, PHP, etc. just generate HTML. Learn the basic tools first.

Comment: As @xbonez mentioned, this question will become a turf war like coke vs pepsi, apple vs mac, linux distro vs linux distro.  Someone is going to claim PHP or Rails or JSP or .NET, etc.  If I had to recommend anything, look into PHP or .NET.  I believe those are the two biggest in terms of jobs.  I do mostly PHP and the loosely typed language can cause poor programming habits if you don't have a background, but it's also a bit easier to get into, imho.

Comment: @jmbertucci: I agree that this is going to be a turf war. I have reported to move to programmers site.

Comment: @HoàngLong Being a subjective question I don't think this will be any more appropriate on programmers. It doesn't ask for specific facts, it is a vague and open-ended question which will only solicit opinion (ie. not facts).

Comment: @Smock: If there's N people read your question, there would be O(N) different answers. None of them are correct or wrong, but mostly subjective. StackOverflow rules doesn't allow that (to avoid endless pointless arguments), and I don't think you'll get much information from your question too. Instead, why don't you should try to be more specific? Ask on programmers.stackexchange.com may help, too.

Comment: @Smock: for example, you may want to give both your 2 solutions(grails / ruby on rails) a quick tour to understand a little about these technology & make a pet project. A quick web book manager shouldn't take more than 14 hours. If in the process you have some difficulties, you can come and ask here. Believe me, just sticking with whatever comes in you hand first: web technology are all built on a same base, and getting it in one technology will help you understand others a lot easier/quicker. Hope this help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I personally use Grails and JavaScript for developing web apps. I like Grails very much, as I used to work with Java and Grails adds many cool features to the old Java and makes it easier to use. But I wouldn't learn Grails now because its future is uncertain. Ruby is a better candidate, but I don't know this language at all.

IMHO Javascript is a must. If you know it well, I guess you can use it both for client side and server side (Node.js). And I think JS will be use much more in the future, so learning it is a good start.

In conclusion, I recommend Javascript.

Cheers,
Lojza

Comment: great answer! I would stay to start learning webserver side programming with PHP because it's easier to understand the fundamentals I guess, because it's the main purpose of the language. But if he has no problem on learning new concepts jumping in ruby or node.js is really a good choice I think.

Comment: Do you have a source for your statement that grails future is uncertain?